# Comparing data in same table - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a course catalog table in which I have catalog codes and course codes for when the courses were offered. What I need to do is to determine when a course isn't being offered any longer and mark it as an archived course.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COURSECATALOG](
    [catalog_code] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [course_code] [char](7) NOT NULL,
    [title] [char](40) NOT NULL,
    [credits] [decimal](7, 4) NULL,

) 

insert into coursecatalog
values 
('200810', 'BIOL101', 'Biology', '3'),
('200810', 'CHEM201', 'Advanced Chemistry', '3'),
('200810', 'ACCT101', 'Beginning Accounting', '3'),
('201012', 'ACCT101', 'Beginning Accounting', '3'),
('201214', 'ACCT101', 'Beginning Accounting', '3'),
('201214', 'ENGL101', 'English Composition', '3'),
('201416', 'PSYC101', 'Psychology', '3'),
('201618', 'PSYC101', 'Psychology', '3'),
('201618', 'BIOL101', 'Biology', '3'),
('201618', 'CHEM201', 'Advanced Chemistry', '3'),
('201618', 'ENGL101', 'English Composition', '3'),
('201618', 'PSYC101', 'Psychology', '3')
```

In this case, I need to return ACCT101 - Beginning Accounting since this isn't being offered anymore and should be considered an archived course.

My code so far:

```
SELECT
catalog_code, course_code
FROM COURSECATALOG t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM COURSECATALOG t2
                   WHERE t2.catalog_code <> t1.catalog_code
                     AND t2.course_code = t1.course_code)
order by 
course_code, catalog_code
```

But this only returns courses that were only ever offered one time (in one catalog). I need to figure out how I can get courses that might have been offered in multiple catalogs but isn't offered any longer.

Any assistance that can be provide is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious. How do you know that ACCT101 is from an old catalog and not a new class in the current catalog? It seems that perhaps the "current" catalog is the largest value of catalog_code? A more normalized structure would make this a lot easier. The addition of a catalog table would make this less ambiguous. I really wish these professors would use better examples for the things they give their students.

Comment: I'm going based on the catalog code. For example, 201618 is a catalog that spans from 2016 - 2018. I'm not sure if it really matters what the current catalog is since I need any course that isn't being offered any longer?

Comment: Right. But I was asking how you know what catalog is current. And pointing out the ambiguity of the data here. If you don't need to know what is the current catalog (or most recent) you have no way of knowing what courses are new and what ones have been retired.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. Yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the catalog_code is a date with YYYYMM format

```
SELECT course_code FROM (
SELECT CONVERT(char, catalog_code,112) AS catalog_code, course_code FROM COURSECATALOG
) AS Q
GROUP BY course_code
HAVING MAX(catalog_code) < '20160101'
```

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/32adfb/14/1

Comment: Thank you, I think this will work for me! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT course_code
FROM COURSECATALOG t1
GROUP BY course_code
HAVING MAX(catalog_code) <> '201618';
```

This assumes that "currently being offered" means that it is in the `201618` catalog.

You could calculate the most recent catalog:

```
SELECT course_code
FROM COURSECATALOG t1
GROUP BY course_code
HAVING MAX(catalog_code) <> (SELECT MAX(catalog_code FROM COURSECATALOG);
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon, for your assistance. It is much appreciated!